# How to hash a PyTorch Tensor

Tags: python, hash, pytorch, tensor, torch

Given a PyTorch Tensor of integers, for example, `torch.Size(N, C, H, W)`.
Is there a way to efficiently hash each element of the tensor such that I get an output from `[-MAX_INT32 to +MAX_INT32]` or `[0 to MAX_INT32]` that fast runs on the GPU?

Also in a way I can perform `output % N`, and each element will be uniformly or almost uniformly distributed from 0 - N.

Comment: Since each element of the tensor is an int which is already hashable (i.e. you can use it as dict keys), what's preventing you from directly using the tensor values themselves as the hash values? I feel like more context on your end goal is needed here.

Comment: My goal is to treat each element of the input as a pseudo random seed and generate a random scaler dependent on that seed for each index using pytorch operations

Comment: OK, so my question is still relevant: what's preventing you from feeding the tensor values directly as seeds _without_ hashing? Why is hashing necessary?

Comment: I Apologize for my unclear statement,The input acts as seeds that are not pseudo random, it is linear for example the input tensor may be a 1d vector with these values [0,20,40,50,65]. If N equaled 10, there will be a problem because input mod 10 will equal [0,0,0,0,5] and will later lead to multiple hash collisions.

Comment: I think the question would be a lot clearer if you provide an example code of what you want to do.

Comment: why not just `hash(tensor)`?

Comment: The simplest approach might be to use a [Linear congruential generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator). It's just multiple, add, modulo. There's also [Thinc](https://pypi.org/project/thinc/) which has a cuda implementation of murmurhash3, but I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: @ValentinGoldité That doesn't satisfy the property `hash(tensor) == hash(tensor.clone())`. Perhaps `hash(tuple(tensor.reshape(-1).tolist()))` is a bit better.

Answer (score 1):

Not GPU-*efficient*, nor cryptographically secure, but an easy way is:

```
def hash_tensor(tensor):
    return hash(tuple(tensor.reshape(-1).tolist()))
```

Test:

```
>>> hash_tensor(torch.arange(8)) == hash_tensor(torch.arange(8))
True

>>> hash_tensor(torch.arange(8)) == hash_tensor(torch.arange(8) + 42)
False
```

Comment: Remember `hash` output is not stable between reruns of the interpreter unless you set PYTHONHASHSEED to a known value.

Answer (score 1):

Below is a "coarsely" parallelized algorithm that works on *integers*, based on the [Linear congruential generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) with [musl/newlib parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator#Parameters_in_common_use).

It works by reducing the last dimension repeatedly until there are no more dimensions remaining. Thus, the total number of on-GPU "for-loop" iterations required are `sum(x.shape)`. If you choose your shape carefully (e.g. `(8, 8, 8, ...)`, this should mean only `8 + 8 + 8 + ...` iterations.

```
import torch
from torch import Tensor


MULTIPLIER = 6364136223846793005
INCREMENT = 1
MODULUS = 2**64


def hash_tensor(x: Tensor) -> Tensor:
    assert x.dtype == torch.int64
    while x.ndim > 0:
        x = _reduce_last_axis(x)
    return x


@torch.no_grad()
def _reduce_last_axis(x: Tensor) -> Tensor:
    assert x.dtype == torch.int64
    acc = torch.zeros_like(x[..., 0])
    for i in range(x.shape[-1]):
        acc *= MULTIPLIER
        acc += INCREMENT
        acc += x[..., i]
        # acc %= MODULUS  # Not really necessary.
    return acc
```

Test:

```
x = torch.arange(8 * 8 * 8 * 8, dtype=torch.int64).reshape(8, 8, 8, 8)

>>> hash_tensor(x)
tensor(2150010819114838296)

>>> hash_tensor(x - 1)
tensor(2225417619311630616)

>>> hash_tensor(x * 2)
tensor(-4806624569712897768)

# Zeroes are OK:
>>> hash_tensor(torch.zeros((8, 8, 8, 8), dtype=torch.int64))
tensor(9106646207942574360)

# "Breaks" if you do a single axis of -1's...
>>> hash_tensor(torch.full((8,), -1))
tensor(0)

# But multiple axes is OKish:
>>> hash_tensor(torch.full((8, 8, 8, 8), -1))
tensor(9182053008139366680)
```

Notes:

- For **non-divisible** tensor lengths, consider padding on the right with zeros until it's a multiple of `(8, 8, 8, ...)` (or however much you want to parallelize).
- For **floating point**, consider either rounding (inaccurate), or using torch.frexp (accurate) to convert to an integer.
- Due to endianness (i.e. byte order), different devices/GPUs may produce different results. To avoid this, you may need to convert your tensor to a correctly-ordered byte stream using something like `[x >> 24, x >> 16, x >> 8, x >> 0]` followed by a flatten.